# Extend site configuration -> site language with a custom field?

Tags: php, typo3, backend, typo3-11.x

How can i extend site configuration -> site language with a custom field?
Default way to extend site configuration is described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ExtendingSiteConfig.html#extending-the-form-gui) and works fine.

But is it possible to extend site_language with custom field?
[image]

I tried the following:

```
$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['columns']['testing'] = [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:gf_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:testing',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'eval' => 'required',
        'default' => 'testing',
    ],
];
$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['types']['0']['showitem'] = str_replace(
    'websiteTitle,',
    'websiteTitle, testing, ',
    $GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['types']['0']['showitem']
);
```

But this throws the following errors

```
PHP Warning
Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Undefined array key 0 in /var/www/html/local_packages/gf_sitepackage/Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/sites.php line 45

PHP Warning
Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/local_packages/gf_sitepackage/Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/sites.php line 45
```

If i try array index 1 as i see at BE with inspect element.

```
$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['types']['1']['showitem'] = str_replace(
    'websiteTitle,',
    'websiteTitle, testing, ',
    $GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['types']['1']['showitem']
);
```

Now i got no error but can´t see the new field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set your Overrides for Site or SiteLanguage in the folder "Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/", see from Documentation:

> The example below shows the experimental feature adding a field to site in an extension's Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/sites.php file.

My Test with our code is the working in the correct folder. If your put the override in "Configuration/TCA/Overrides" the you become the PHP Warnings and nothing is show.

**Update 2023-03-18 (Working Example):**

Override Site Language in ***your_extension_key/Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/site_language.php***

```php
<?php
# Override Backend editor Site configuration => language

// Configure a new select field to site language
$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['columns']['extensionLanguage'] = [
    'label' => 'Sprache für Extensions',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'itemsProcFunc' => \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Configuration\TCA\ItemsProcessorFunctions::class . '->populateAvailableLanguagesFromSites',
        'eval' => 'required, int',
    ],
];

// And add it to showitem
$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['palettes']['default']['showitem'] = str_replace(
    'title, ',
    'title, extensionLanguage, ',
    $GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['palettes']['default']['showitem']
);
```

Greeting Kay

Comment: My sites.php is in the folder Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/. Could you publish some functional code?

Comment: Hi @ntiedt, I just implemented something like this today for a project of my company. It was only necessary to have this file under "my_extension_key/Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/site_language.php" with this content:

https://gist.github.com/Neowar/b38402dac17b7fc2c98a031883ce7f91

Comment: Ahh this works great. Thanks in advance. If you integrate your code directly within yout 1. answer i can mark it as correct answer ;-)

Comment: Working code is added in the answer :-)